# Javascript dom manipulation textarea value doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, console, browser-automation

when typing into textarea with keyboard and clicking button with js working np.
When changing textarea value with javascript. Does not work.
And textarea has eventListener name invalid. When i see this event changing textarea value with javascript doesn't work always.
Button working but textarea not.
What should i do ?. I tried to change everything in textarea but doesn't work.

```
var text = document.querySelector("textarea")
var btn = document.querySelector("btn")

text.value = "hello"
text.innerText = "hello"
text.textContent = "hello"
text.innerHtml = "hello"
text._valueTracker.setValue("hello")
text.defaultValue = "hello"

btn.click();
```

When try to fill textarea like this code and click btn : acting like textarea value is empty.
When typing into textarea with keyboard and click btn with js its working.

also :

```
getEventListeners(text);

{invalid: Array(1)}
invalid: Array(1)
0:listener:ƒ ()
once:false
passive:false
type:"invalid"
useCapture:false
[[Prototype]]:Object
length:1
[[Prototype]]:Array(0)
[[Prototype]]:Object
```

Actually i tried different atleast 5 website . Really noticed that :

Textarea that im trying to change value with js if has " Invalid " named event Not working changing value with js.
Otherwise working normally.

Why not working when contains " invalid " named event ?

Comment: `text.value` should work.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar if this code works why i create question here. That was already first try text.value = "asdas" , ->  then btn.click(); ofcourse

Comment: What code? You're calling `getEventListeners()`, but there's nothing that adds an event listener.

Comment: @Barmar i don't call eventListener . I just showed here.

Comment: `getEventListeners()` shows that there's a listener on the textarea, so you must be calling `text.addEventListener()` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To change what's in a `textarea`, you can use `value`, but you can also use `.textContent`.

- `.textContent` can be used to set or get content from a `textarea`,
  but if the user has edited the `textarea`, `.value` must be used to
  obtain that user entered data.
- `.value` can be exclusively used to set or retrieve the contents of
  the `textarea`.

Because a `textarea` element is an element that has an explicit closing tag, the element will have "content" and that content can be accessed with `.textContent`. The `value` attribute (HTML) and `value` property (DOM) are for elements like `input` that do not have a closing tag, so therefore they can't have any "content".

```js
document.querySelector("textarea").textContent = "HELLO";

document.querySelector("textarea").value += " WORLD";
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

The code you've show initiates a `click` event on a button, but (as far as we can tell) you haven't set up an event handler for the button, so calling `click` on it would do nothing.

Also, your code of `var btn = document.querySelector("btn")` attempts to find an element of the type "btn", which there isn't in HTML. If you gave your `button` an `id` of `btn`, then the line should be:

`var btn = document.querySelector("#btn")`

This is an example of how it could be set up:

```js
var text = document.querySelector("textarea")
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  text.textContent = "hello world"
  console.log(text.textContent);  // Gets data stored with .textContent
  console.log(text.value); // Gets contents of textarea after user has edited.
});
```

```html
<button type="button">Click Me</button>
Type some text in the textarea and then click the button
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: This is backwards. `.value` is correct.

Comment: @Barmar `.textContent` is correct. See the example.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ph83n5vg/

Comment: `textContent` is only used for the initial value. Once the user has edited it, you have to use `value`. See https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ph83n5vg/4/ and compare what happens if you click before or after typing into the text area.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I was updating my answer to show this.

Comment: I tried everything. thats why asking question here.

text.value = "hello"
btn.click();

doesn't work.

text.textContent = "hello"
btn.click(); 

doesn't work.

I tried every option 1 by 1. All does not work.

Comment: @Nick Did you see the part of my answer where I pointed out two potential mistakes in your code?

Comment: @ScottMarcus i tried every option 1 by 1 . All doesn't work.
i just change value and click ofcourse that was first try . Then i after tried things like 2 days entire day . Nothing work

Comment: @Nick But, as you can see from running my code right here, it does work, so you must have some other issue.

Comment: @ScottMarcus thats not my website. Button events already implemented. So imagine like chat when writing with keyboard button sending value . When writing with js button doesnt send acting like value = empty. ""
Tyring same thing in other website as an example textarea has " input named event "  
when i type dispatchEvent(input one.) working in other website. 
But this one has " invalid named event " and not working even dispatch on textarea before click ..

Comment: @ScottMarcus i edited question. And I'm pretty sure problem about " invalid " named event. But why and how to bypass it idk.